# Jest not executing test case inside forEach function

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs

I am trying to execute test case in a loop inside a forEach block, but variable which i am iterating always throws undefined. In beforeAll block i am using await to get a data from database and I am assigning array of objects to a variable so that i can iterate the array and execute the test for each object. but when i try to do that it always throws **TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined**, can anyone say what i am doing wrong here?

sample.test.ts

```
describe('Test suite ', () => {
  let d: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    connectToDatabase();
    d = await r.retriveDataFromDb1();
  }, 200000);
  describe('Test suite 1', () => {
    d.forEach(function(v: any) {
      it('test case', async () => {
        console.log(v);
      }, 20000);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Jest tests may run asynchronously but they are defined synchronously. `beforeAll` executes only when tests are started, test are supposed to be known at this time.

It can be either a single test that creates assertions dynamically:

```
  let d: any;
  beforeAll(async () => {
    connectToDatabase();
    d = await r.retriveDataFromDb1();
  }, 200000);

  describe('Test suite 1', () => {
    it('test case', () => {
      d.forEach((v: any) => {
        expect(some).toBe(valueThatDependsOnV);
      });
    }, 20000);
  });
```

Or asynchronous setup should take place in [global setup](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#globalsetup-string) where it's allowed:

```
// setup.js
module.exports = async () => {
  connectToDatabase();
  global.__d__ = await r.retriveDataFromDb1();
};

// teardown.js
module.exports = async function () {
  // disconnect from database
};
```

`__d__` will become available in all tests:

```
  describe('Test suite 1', () => {
    __d__.forEach((v: any) => {
      it('test case', async () => {
        ...
      }, 20000);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Tried on your first solution, but it exeits when first failure occurs in a loop, but i need results for all the objects available in variable d(where d is type of [{}]). secong solution is not possible in my scenario as configration may vary from module to module. Is nested test cases are possible in jest?

Comment: As for the first case, you can collect errors with try..catch and rethrow them at the end of the test, it's not clean but it should work and can be rewritten as helper function if you need this multiple times. As for the second case, you can assign data for each test file in global setup and identify it with absolute test path, so it could be accessed as `__d__[__filename]` in tests, not clean but workable. By nested cases do you mean `it` inside of `it`? This is not allowed, and again, all tests should be known to Jest before it runs them, so you cannot define them after a testrun begins.