# Passing param to Jest's each() from async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, jestjs

I am trying to dynamically create set of tests with Jest's `test.each()` feature.

First, I have to set the variable via async function and it seems to be tricky thing to do in Jest.
When the variable is set in beforeAll(), it is too late and variable is *undefined* when `test.each()` is executed.

So I tried to use `globalSetup` option as mentioned in this [asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61322027/1861097).
But when debugging, the global variable is also shown as undefined, odd.

Is there any way to pass such variable to parameterised test in Jest?

```
describe.only('Param tests', () => {
    test.each(global.__sites__)('Params', (host) => {
        console.log(host);
    });
});
```

```
//setup.js
const Loader = require('./Loader.js');

module.exports = async () => {
    await Loader.getSites().then(data => {
        global.__sites__ = data.filter(record => record.length > 4);
    });
};
```

```
//jest.config.js
module.exports = {
  testTimeout: 20000,
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ["expect-puppeteer"],
  globalSetup: "./setup.js"
};
```

Comment: How did you execute setup.js?

Comment: through jest.config.js - added to the question

Comment: You aren't returning anything from your setup.js function. If you return your promise, jest might wait for it to resolve.

Comment: don't think it matters, there is a global environment set and it goes through it while debug step by step, but it is just not accessible inside the test itself later on

Comment: Timing with promises can be tricky. Since you aren't returning anything from your setup.js function, Jest will continue on without waiting for it to resolve (well, it did wait, but it just waited for your implicit return of `resolve(undefined)`). If the test runs before it resolves, your global won't be set. Just try returning the `Loader.getSites()...` promise and see if it works. Another thing you can try is not setting that global inside a promise. Just set it with dummy data, see if it ends up in the test. If it doesn't, the issue isn't promises.

Comment: Also, you can do this in `beforeAll`. You just need to return a promise. Jest will wait for it to resolve.

Comment: thanks for the tips, I just tried to set simple global and it won't make it to the test, so the issue is somewhere else, will try to see if there is any other option